# How do I suppress POM and IVY related warnings in Gradle 7?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

After upgrading to Gradle 7 I have many warnings like:

```
Cannot publish Ivy descriptor if ivyDescriptor not set in task ':myProject:artifactoryPublish' and task 'uploadArchives' does not exist.
Cannot publish pom for project ':myProject' since it does not contain the Maven plugin install task and task ':myProject:artifactoryPublish' does not specify a custom pom path.
```

The artifactoryPublish task works fine.

My Gradle script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories{
        maven {
            url = '...'
            credentials {
                username '...'
                password '...'
            }
            metadataSources {
                mavenPom()
                artifact()
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.24.12"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            suppressAllPomMetadataWarnings()
        }
    }  
}

group = '...'

artifactory {
    contextUrl = '...'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = '...'
            username = '...'
            password = '...'
        }
        defaults {  
            publishConfigs('archives')  
            publishIvy = false 
            publications("mavenJava")       
        }
    }
}
```

How do I disable those warnings?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you mixed between the old Gradle publish-configuration method and the new Gradle publication method.

You applied the [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin which allows creating [publications](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:publications). In `artifactory.default`, you added the "mavenJava" publication as expected.

However, the [archives](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/artifact_management.html#sec:archive_task_artifacts) publish-configuration doesn't exist in your build.gradle file. Basically, publish-configurations are created by the legacy [maven](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/maven_plugin.html) plugin. The configured `mavenJava` publication does the same as the `archives` publish-configuration and therefore all of the JARs are published as expected.

To remove the warning messages you see, remove the `publishConfigs('archives')` from artifactory.default clause:

```
artifactory {
    publish {
        defaults {  
            publishConfigs('archives') // <-- Remove this line
            publishIvy = false 
            publications("mavenJava")       
        }
    }
}
```

Read more:

1. [Gradle Artifactory plugin documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin)
2. [Example](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/gradle-example-publish)